# Как в цикле while при введении буквенного значения повторить сам цикл?

Tags: python, while

```py
while True:  
    h = int(input("How much stairs?: "))
    if h <= 8 and h >= 1:
         break
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при введении буквы цикл тоже повторялся. Пока-что выводиться только ошибка в данном случае.

Comment: поместите код в читаемом виде согласно правилам сообщества.

Answer (score 0):

Мы просто пробуем выполнить ввод числа и при ошибке выходим из цикла

```
while True:
    try:
        h = int(input("Enter number of stairs: "))
    except:
        continue
    if 8 >= h >= 1:
        break
```

Comment: А нужно наоборот не выходить!

Comment: в чем проблема поменять break на pass или continue

Comment: В чем проблема внимательно прочитать вопрос?